# Find common denominator for list entries Python

Tags: python, list

I am calling a Python function several times and it returns a list with either one of the following:

1) single entry

2) multiple entry

3)blank list

For example:

```
a=['aaaaa']
b=['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc']
c=['aaaaa']
d=['ppppp', 'aaaaa']
e=['aaaaa', 'uuuuu']
```

Now, I want to find the common string in all the lists.
I can do it as follows for TWO lists:

```
intercept_list=[val for val in a if val in b]
```

Is it possible to do it for multiple list in one go? Also supposing list "e" returned an empty list, I just want to ignore it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
set.intersection(*(set(s) for s in list_of_lists if s))
```

For example:

```
>>> a=['aaaaa']
>>> b=['aaaaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc']
>>> c=['aaaaa']
>>> d=['ppppp', 'aaaaa']
>>> e=['aaaaa', 'uuuuu']
>>> f=[]
>>> list_of_lists = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
>>> set.intersection(*(set(s) for s in list_of_lists if s))
set(['aaaaa'])
```

Comment: The set(s) call is unnecessary or? simply passing the list should give the same result.

Comment: @M4rtini: try it yourself. :^)

Comment: I just did, same result and slightly faster without set(s). or no nvm :P i did set(a).intersection(...)

Comment: That's very surprising.  You should be getting `TypeError: descriptor 'intersection' requires a 'set' object but received a 'list'`, as [here](http://codepad.org/7QuKmrTs).

Comment: yea as i said. i did set(a).intersection(...) or in this case it would be `set(list_of_lists[0]).intersection(*(s for s in list_of_lists[1:] if s))`

Comment: @M4rtini: that assumes that `list_of_lists[0]` isn't the one that's empty, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`intersection()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
>>> set(a).intersection(b, c, d, e)
set(['aaaaa'])
```

You can use `list()` to convert this back to a list:

```
result = list(set(a).intersection(b, c, d, e))
```

Comment: This fails if any list is empty.

Comment: @adsmith: that's correct right? If any given list is empty then the intersection is also empty.

Comment: @SimeonVisser The question explicitly states to ignore empty lists, I also misread that.

Comment: its ok, I will do a TRY -EXCEPT to check and make sure if the list is empty and work around empty lists. You are right, if I simply use everything including empty lists, the answer is []

Answer (score 0):

A more generic implementation, counts the number of occurrence of the elements and verify if the count matches the list count

```
>>> def find_common(*args):
    from collections import Counter
    from itertools import takewhile, imap
    from operator import itemgetter
    count = sum(1 for e in args if e)
    args = chain.from_iterable(args)
    result =  map(itemgetter(0), 
                   takewhile(lambda e: e[-1] ==  count,
                             Counter(args).most_common()))
    return result

>>> find_common(a,b,c,d,e)
['aaaaa']
>>> f = []
>>> find_common(a,b,c,d,e, f)
['aaaaa']
```

Comment: question explicitly asks to ignore empty lists